# Can't get gdx-setup-ui working on windows

Tags: libgdx

I downloaded the latest nightly and am trying to setup a project. I double click on the `gdx-setup-ui.jar` file but it does nothing. When I go to the commandline(as admin) and run :

`java -jar gdx-setup-ui.jar`

this is spit out

> C:\Libgdx\libgdx-nightly-20140305>java -jar gdx-setup-ui.jar
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: new c
>   hild is null
>           at javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode.insert(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode.add(Unknown Source)
>           at aurelienribon.gdxsetupui.ui.panels.PreviewPanel$ResultTree.update(Unk
>   nown Source)
>           at aurelienribon.gdxsetupui.ui.panels.PreviewPanel$ResultTree.(Unk
>   nown Source)
>           at aurelienribon.gdxsetupui.ui.panels.PreviewPanel.(Unknown Source
>   )
>           at aurelienribon.gdxsetupui.ui.MainPanel.(Unknown Source)
>           at aurelienribon.gdxsetupui.ui.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
>   ce)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Things that I have already tried are:

- uninstall and re-install jdk
- restart computer
- redownload all of the libgdx files
- search google and stackoverflow

Comment: I am having the same problem.  I wonder if it has something to do with   badlogicgames moving from their wiki to github :/

Comment: @RedCricket That has already happened several months ago actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading an older version.

If it works properly without problems, then there might be some problem with nightly (which I believe would be fixed soon) otherwise the problem lies with your system.

This may not be a particular solution, but it'd narrow down the things to look for (error).

Good luck.

Comment: It's the nightly, where should i post that I am getting an error?